# replace single quotes and double quotes from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, parsing

I am a trying to learn python and I have an issue where I encounter string that has both single and double quotes that I need to replace. My objective would be to split them to a list but still preserve the single and double quotes for other reasons. I tried the below but getting the errors

```
s=("I said, "hello" it's mine".replace(""",'`')).replace("'","^")
print(s)

File "<ipython-input-58-a5276888c42f>", line 1
    s=("I said, "hello" it's mine".replace(""",'`')).replace("'","^")
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need to *escape* the double-quotes in the string by using a backslash, e.g. `s="I said, \"hello\" it's mine"`. Otherwise it can't tell if they are meant to be the end of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a backslash to escape the double-quotes.

```
s = "I said, \"hello\" it's mine"
```

Or use a single-quoted string and escape the single-quote. (This is the canonical representation.)

```
s = 'I said, "hello" it\'s mine'
```

Or use triple-quotes - single or double.

```
s = """I said, "hello" it's mine"""
s = '''I said, "hello" it's mine'''
```